# Python 2.7: error in Canny Edge detection TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv3.0, canny-operator

I am using Canny edge detection algorithm in Python 2.7.12 with image (.jpg)

[image]

I used following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('35.jpg')  
edges = cv2.Canny(img,150,200)
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Edge Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

But it shows me error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/test4.py", line 11, in <module>
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3157, in imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5124, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 596, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

I saw many answers related to this but I am unable to rectify it. I also observed that **if I save same image as .png then code run perfectly**.What modifications should I need in code to run for .jpg files?
Thanks.

Comment: That sometimes occurs if your image name or extension is wrong. Check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code.
Your problem occur when I pass incorrect image path to  cv2.imread. 
Otherwise, it works fine.
So first of all just try to check path to image.